# Наследник для FileInputStream Java

Tags: java

Задача написать класс, который в конструкторе будет принимать имя файла, если файл с расширением .txt, то создавать объект FileInputStream, если нет - выбрасывать исключение. Я попытался в самом начале сделать проверку на расширение, если txt, то вызывать конструктор суперкласса, ежели нет, то выбрасывать исключение, но ide ругается, что я обязательно должен вызвать конструктор суперкласса первой же строчкой.

```
public class TxtInputStream extends FileInputStream {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;

    public TxtInputStream(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedFileNameException, IOException {
        String [] fileNameArray = fileName.split(" ");
        if (fileNameArray[fileNameArray.length].equals("txt"))
            this.fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        else {
            throw new UnsupportedFileNameException();
            super.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

UPD добавлю требования к задаче:

1. Класс **TxtInputStream должен наследоваться от класса FileInputStream**.

2. Если в конструктор передан txt-файл, TxtInputStream должен вести себя, как обычный FileInputStream.

3. Если в конструктор передан не txt-файл, должно быть выброшено исключение UnsupportedFileNameException.

4. В случае выброшенного исключения, так же должен быть вызван super.close().

Comment: Так обертка или наследник?

Comment: Видимо таки наследник.

Comment: реализуйте задачу с помощью шаблона проектирования "Заместитель"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если наследник, то удалите переменную `FileInputStream fileInputStream;`

и конструктор будет выглядеть так:

```
 public TxtInputStream(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedFileNameException, IOException {
    super(fileName);
    if(!fileName.endsWith("txt")){
        throw new UnsupportedFileNameException();
    }
}
```

---

Если надо сделать как обертку:

тогда удаляем наследование и оставляем переменную `FileInputStream fileInputStream;`, только делаем её приватной.

тогда конструктор выглядит так:

```
public TxtInputStream(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedFileNameException, IOException {
    if(fileName.endsWith("txt"))
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    else{
        throw new UnsupportedFileNameException();
    }
}
```

но в этом случае необходимо создать нужные вам методы и перенаправить их в объект `fileInputStream`.

Comment: В первом варианте у Вас сразу вызывается конструктор суперкласса, мне же надо, чтобы он вызывался только в том случае, если файл имеет расширение txt

Comment: @fonzy это требования языка. Может каким-то таймы хитросплетением это можно обойти, ноя  такого способа не знаю. Любой наследник обязан первой строкой вызывать конструктор родителя. Если это не подходит используйте второй способ.

Comment: Нда, оказалось я неправильно понял условие задачи. Конструктор суперкласса вызывается в любом случае, но если в конструктор нашего класса передан не txt файл, то выбрасывается исключение.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TxtReader {

    private final String FILE_NAME;

    public TxtReader(String fileName) {
        this.FILE_NAME=fileName;
    }

    private boolean checkName() {
        try {
            return ".txt".equals(FILE_NAME.substring(FILE_NAME.length() - 4));
        } catch (NullPointerException | StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public FileInputStream createFileInputStream() throws IOException, UnsupportedFileNameException {
        if (checkName()==false) throw new UnsupportedFileNameException();
        return new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);
    }

    public List <String> loadTxtFile(FileInputStream fileInputStream) throws IOException{
        List <String>list = new ArrayList <>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream))) {
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) list.add(strLine);
            return list;
        }
    }

    //for testing
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String fileName  = "catalog/file.txt";
        TxtReader txtReader = new TxtReader(fileName);
        FileInputStream inputStream = txtReader.createFileInputStream();
        List<String> loadTxtFile = txtReader.loadTxtFile(inputStream);

        for (String s : loadTxtFile) System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

методом лоад можете даже прочитать построчно и получить соответсвующую коллекцию